# Best way share Business Objects between a universal app and windows desktop application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a windows application in my project that contains all my business objects. These are just POCO entities. These business objects are accessed through various other projects such as web services, business layer, etc...

Now I'm build a universal app for both windows store app and windows phone and I'm having a problem as I can't see how to share the existing business objects from my windows desktop app.

I thought I'd be allowed to create a folder in my shared project (the library/project shared between the windows and windows phone app) and simply add the relevant POCO classes as a reference "link" but that does seems to be allowed.

I then thought I'd create a new shared PCL project and again, try to add "link" references to these POCO classes from my windows desktop app but I was not allowed to "link" these files to the project. I can only add and copy.

I obviously don't want to have 2 copies of these, as it will only cause problems if any of these POCO classes get out of sync.

Is my only option to build a PCL library and add these POCO classes to it, then remove the existing classes from my windows desktop app and reference the PCL file to it instead or is there a way I can link these without having to duplicate them ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can share libraries across all platforms is if they are PCL; anything can reference a PCL library. To have this utility, PCL libraries cannot be tied to platform specifics, so they can only reference other PCL libraries; this is why you could not reference a Windows assembly containing your POCOs from a PCL. So, your business objects need to go into a PCL in order for them to be available by project reference across multiple platform types. If your business objects are, as you say, POCO, there should be no problem with housing them in a PCL.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I'll have to do a bit of cleaning up, but nothing major, so transferring them won't be a problem. Thanks.